# Firebase Blaze Plan Quota Exceeded

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send messages using conditions every 2 minutes but sometimes the server response is:

**Topic quota exceeded**

The response says that this is a *RESOURCE_EXCEEDED* error but it doesn't make sense because if I use the same interval using topics individually, it works perfectly.

Here's the payload:

```
{
"condition": "'topic1' in topics && !('topic2' in topics) && !('topic3' in topics) && !('topic4' in topics)",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Foo",
        "body": "Bar"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.